# How to Find Exact Row in Log File

Tags: algorithm

If you have a big log file, billions of lines long. The files have some columns, like IP addresses: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

How can I find exact one line quickly, like if I want to find `123.123.123.123`.

A naive line-by-line search seems too slow.

Comment: Binary search, assuming the entries are in some sort of order.  If they're not in any order then there's no choice but a full search.

Comment: without more detail, a linear search is as good as it gets

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other information to go on (such as a date range, assuming the file is sorted), then line-by-line search is your best option.  Now, that doesn't mean you need to read in lines.  Also, it might be more efficient for you to search backwards because you know the entry is recent.

The general approach (for searching backwards) is this:

Declare a buffer.  You will read chunks of the file at a time into this buffer as fast as possible (preferably by using low-level operating system calls that can read directly without any buffering/caching).

So you seek to the end of your file minus the size of your buffer and read that many bytes.

Now you search forwards through your buffer for the first newline character.  Remember that offset for later, as it represents a partial line.  Starting at next line, you search forward to the end of the buffer looking for your string.  If it has to be in a certain column but other columns could contain that value, then you need to do some parsing.

Now you continue to search backwards through your file.  You seek to the last position you read from minus the chunk size *plus the offset that you found when you searched for a newline character*.  Now, you read again.  If you like you can move that partial line to the end of the buffer and read fewer bytes but it's not going to make a huge difference if your chunks are large enough.

And you continue until you reach the beginning of the file.  There is of course a special case when the number of bytes to read is less than the chunk size (namely, you don't ignore the first line).  I assume that you won't reach the beginning of the file because it seems clear that you don't want to search the entire thing.

So that's the approach when you have no idea where the value is.  If you do have some idea on ordering, then of course you probably want to do a binary search.  In that case you can use smaller chunk sizes (enough to at least catch a full line).

Answer (score 0):

You really need to search for some regularity in the file and exploit that, Barring that, then   if you have more processors you could split the file into sections and search in parallel - assuming I/O would not then be a bottleneck.